# What is the use of "Much best"?

Tags: phrases

Can anybody describe "Much best"

> Socrates: And you know best of all men how to transmit that to another
>
> Hippias: **Much best**, Socrates

The source is Chapter 13 - Hippias Major, near the  top of page 390 from the book Dialogues of Plato (written by Plato :-?) 
"THE DIALOGUES OF PLATO TRANSLATED INTO ENGLISH WITH ANALYSES AND INTRODUCTIONS
BY
B. JOWETT, M.A.
Master of Balliol College Regius
Professor of Greek in the University of
Oxford Doctor in Theology of the
University of Leyden"
http://pendientedemigracion.ucm.es/info/diciex/gente/agf/plato/The_Dialogues_of_Plato_v0.1.pdf

Comment: This is not English. It is either a joke, or translated by somebody who does not speak English. What is the source?

Comment: Hi Colin, please help, for English is not my first language; The source is Chapter 13 - Hippias Major, near the  top of page 390 from the book Dialogues of Plato (written by Plato :-?) 
"THE DIALOGUES OF PLATO TRANSLATED INTO ENGLISH WITH ANALYSES AND INTRODUCTIONS
BY
B. JOWETT, M.A.
Master of Balliol College Regius
Professor of Greek in the University of
Oxford Doctor in Theology of the
University of Leyden"
http://pendientedemigracion.ucm.es/info/diciex/gente/agf/plato/The_Dialogues_of_Plato_v0.1.pdf

Comment: how do you now it's not English ?

Comment: I guess "much" means the same thing here as it does in "much better". It's not an idiomatic use, at least not currently.

Comment: @michael.hor257k 'I guess X means' is inadmissible. I can't prove a negative, but I'm pretty sure it's ungrammatical. 'Much the best' means 'by far the best'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth **1**. It's a little more than a guess. **2.** If it's inadmissible, then don't admit it. **3.** Take it up with the editors of the publication (in 1871) who have gone to great lengths to ensure its quality (read the preface).

Comment: Humph. OK. This has never, as far as I can tell, been idiomatic in English. COHA (the Corpus of Historical American English) has precisely two instances of "much best" - but one of them is part of a different structure ("how much best tableware have you?") The NOW corpus has 30 instances, but nearly all of them involve the expressions "pretty much" or "how much". It doesn't occur at all in the COCA (current American English) or BNC (Biritsh English) corpora. So, yes, "much best" is not idiomatic in English. I guess Jowett was trying to render an elliptic expression in Greek into English.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Have they really. I'll take Colin's research as being less subjective.

Comment: @ColinFine That would be my guess too. He explains his approach to translation quite well (even if at length) in the preface.